# Complicated xpath for a rookie

Tags: xpath

I have this piece of html:

```
<tr>
  <td class="has-checkbox">
    <input id="abc" class=... value=...>
  </td>
  <td class="has-label">
    <label for="abc">Name1234</label>
  </td>
<tr>
```

I need to make an xpath that gets me the input element, based on whats in the label, in this case Name1234.

In other words, for this case, I need an xpath to the input element, and the path must contain Name1234, as its variable.

Anyone who can help me out here?

Comment: What xpath have you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

`//input[@id = //label[. = 'Name1234']/@for]` selects `input` element(s) with an `id` attribute value equal to the `for` attribute value of `label` elements where the contents is `Name1234`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/..` , this syntax use to move back to parent node. In your case:

```
//label[.='Name1234']/../../td/input
```

You must move back 2 times because `input` tag is the child of another `td` tag.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) are others introduction and example about you should read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the Axes `parent` and `preceding-sibling`:

`//label[.='Name1234']/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td/input`

Answer (score 0):

It's not so complicated as you think:

```
xpath=//tr[//label[.="Name1234"]]//input
```

in other words, you are looking for the 'tr' which contains 'label' with text "Name1234". If the condition is true, you are getting the 'input' element